# Java && operators

Tags: java, string, if-statement, operator-keyword

I'm trying to make simple if statement , I need to see if my two String's values are not empty (does not equal "").
I use && operator , but sadly , it only checks one string properly if it's not empty , and if the second string is empty, he passes . Making && kinda useless for me.

```
if ( StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(name) && StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(sname)
            ) {do something}
```

I need them both to be checked properly . If at least one string is empty return false .
If both are not empty return true.

Comment: Mentally translate your code into English - "If the name is null or empty, and the surname is null or empty, then do something." Then you can see why it does what it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently your condition is true if both Strings are null or empty.

If you want both **not** to be null or empty you need :

```
if ( !StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(name) && !StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(sname)
        ) {do something}
```

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is smart and if first condition is false it doesn't try the second.
use `&` could achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your check is wrong. You want it to only pass if both ARE empty.

So you should go for

```
if ( !StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(name) && !StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(sname)
        ) {do something}
```

or if u want to catch it in the if statement if one of them IS empty, you should use or:

```
if ( StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(name)|| StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(sname)
        ) {do something}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isNullOrEmpty` will return true if name is empty, but you want it NOT empty, so negate the conditions using !.

```
if ( !StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(name) && !StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(sname)
        ) {do something}
```

**Another alternative is:**

if (!(StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(name) || StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(sname)
            )) {do something}

However, the above is not a recommended coding style, as it is difficult to catch the ! hidden just before the line, and code readers may get confused.

About || and && operators optimized checking:

|| checks for the first true condition from left to right and skips any further checking if it finds one true condition.

&& checks for the first false condition from left to right and skips any further checking if it finds one false condition.

Answer (score 0):

At first it didn't looked any sense to me , and it didn't worked . Only then I realized that I need to to flip the return statements.

```
if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(name) && !StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(sname)) {
        System.out.println("ok");
        return true;}
else {
        System.out.println("empty names");
        return false;
    }
```

Now it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using **'&'**  as `logical operator` you can do the following thing. Here we have not use `StringUtils` -

```
if(   ( null!=name && !name.isEmpty() ) &   
( null!=sname && !sname.isEmpty() )   ){do something}
```